# Is there a significant difference between the version of Aaron seen in the first bench scene and the version of Aaron seen in the second bench scene?

Tags: primer

A key scene in the movie Primer is when Aaron is trying to convince Abe to invite Rachel to the party. The following dialogue takes place at about the 1:08:45 mark.

> AARON: I mean this way we know exactly what happens. We have complete
> control over it. At the end of the night, this guy is arrested and
> goes to jail. That's the way it goes -- your words, not mine.
>
> AARON: Now, come on -- it has to be you. She said she was there
> because you told her you would be there.
>
> [Pause.]
>
> AARON: (Don't) Tell me I came back and did this for nothing.
>
> [Pause.]
>
> ABE:   He doesn't fire.
>
> AARON: No! He didn't fi--
>
> ABE:   He never fires, not even when you rushed him.
>
> AARON: No! He didn't the time I wasn't there. Uh, he didn't the time I
> was, when I rushed him, and... y'know from (what) Rob-- Robert tells
> you he didn't do it tonight. He doesn't have the nerve. I mean the
> guy-- [exhales] We know everything, OK? We're prescient.
>
> ABE:   We can still be careful. Maybe we can get to the gun without
> him knowing.
>
> AARON: We definitely can. I mean he leaves it in the truck, uh, before
> he goes in. We don't even need to, but, I mean if it makes you feel
> better--

Aaron's first line refers to Abe's secondhand report from Robert in his pre-failsafe timeline (the "Is Hero even here?" scene at around 00:48:35). Presumably Abe recounted this to Aaron off-screen at some point in this timeline prior to this scene.

Aaron's second line refers to an event from Aaron's past, which we can deduce includes a conversation with Rachel prior to his arrival in this scene's timeline via replaced failsafe. Note that the protagonist Abe that we viewers have been following did not even go to the party in his pre-failsafe timeline, so this implies either that Abe did go or at least told Rachel that he intended to go in the timeline to which Aaron is referring.

Aaron's fifth line implies that he has already gone back at least twice. We can guess that the timeline in which he wasn't at the party is from his "original" timeline prior to discovery of Abe's failsafe. We can guess that the timeline in which he rushed the gunman was from an iteration (from Aaron's perspective) prior to the one containing this scene; it seems like this would be a timeline that both this Aaron and the narrating/departing Aaron have in common.

Aaron's sixth line implies a certain familiarity with the scenario, which is later reinforced by the depiction of Aaron preventing Abe from smashing the truck window. Together these suggest that the Aaron in this scene may have already "recycled" the replaced failsafe several times.

Is the Aaron from Abe's pre-failsafe timeline (i.e. the one whom Abe berates in the fountain scene for having risked his life for Rachel's sake) the "same" Aaron as the one in this scene? In other words, has the Aaron from the first bench scene -- the one that viewers see in Abe's pre-failsafe timeline -- gone back the same number of times as the Aaron from the second bench scene that is also in this scene?

If yes, then why does the Aaron from the first bench scene not try to convince Abe to invite Rachel to the party? If no, then how is it that Abe's past in the first bench scene includes an earlier "generation" of Aaron?

Note that there is a slight difference in Aaron's bench scene dialogue between the versions experienced by Abe pre- and post-failsafe: "Your work, your cell." at 00:20:00 and "Your cell, your work." at 01:30:10, which suggests either an intentional difference in the portrayal of Aaron by Carruth or a minor continuity error.

Comment: My personal take on primer is that the makers set out to be obtuse and that it doesn't make any sense because they had no intention of having it make sense